# Unable to push elements in a new array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am writing a very easy function where I am checking the even numbers from an array of integer and adding those even numbers into the new array.
But after getting the even numbers from first array when I am trying to push into second array its showing undefined.

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
const newArr = [];

const loop = () => {
 for (var item of array) {
  if (item % 2 == 0) {
   console.log(item);
   newArr.push(item);
  }
 }
};

console.log(loop());
```

Output

2
4
6
undefined

Why new array is showing undefined.

Comment: loop is returning undefined

Comment: You push to `newArr` but never do anything to it or print it

Comment: `loop()` has no `return` statement, therefore, it implicitly produces `undefined`. And when you log the return value of executing the function `loop()` you see this `undefined` in the console.

Comment: `arr` is defined: check ... `newArr` is defined: checked ... code iterates over `array` ... which is nowhere to be seen: check

Comment: FYI, things you might want to learn: [JavaScript return](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_return.asp), [JavaScript Scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Comment: Oh my bad I forgot to return newArr.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply with forEach.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
const newArr = [];


arr.forEach(item => {
  if (item % 2 == 0) {
   newArr.push(item);
  }
})

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why OP's code wasn't working, nor why your code does work.

Answer (score 0):

either return the newArray or execute the loop method and print the new Array.

The reason why you get undefined is because loop is currently a void operator and returning nothing. so if you want the loop method to return the array then the second code sample I showed is the better solution. if you just want to print the array then the first one does the trick.

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
const newArr = [];


arr.forEach(item => {
  if (item % 2 == 0) {
   newArr.push(item);
  }
})

console.log(newArr);
```

or

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

const loop = () => {
 const newArr = [];
 for (var item of arr) {
  if (item % 2 == 0) {
   console.log(item);
   newArr.push(item);
  }
 }
 return newArr
};
console.log(loop());
```

both will work.

Comment: in your 2nd solution why have you put `loop()` inside  console.log() even if inside loop() we have an `return newArr` used.

Comment: _"because loop is currently a void."_ You might want to reword that.  @Digvijay: What else would you have put in the `console.log`?

Comment: @Digvijay well i don't know exactly what your use case is for the loop method. i just thought it could've been your use case as your question has loop in the console log

Comment: @Cerbrus hey, i tried to add some information. if you think I'm missing something, please edit so that I can approve it and maybe learn something aswell.

Comment: That's a lot better! Note that users above 2k rep can't "suggest" edits, any more. Edits by those users just get applied :-)